# Django admin anotate not work with change list view queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I need to create a summary view for a list of records grouped by year, month and category. When I use the model manager and do annotating it works fine, and summary is correctly created. However, if I use the `changelist_view` request objetcts' queryset it duplicate ungrouped records as well. See the two code listings below.

**Correct Values:**

```
Bill.objects.values_list('category__name', 'year', 'month').annotate(Sum('amount'), due=Sum(F('amount') - F('paid_amount'), output_field=models.FloatField()))

<QuerySet [('Insurance', '2019', 'FEB', Decimal('35200.2300000000'), 25200.230000000003), ('Telephone', '2019', 'AUG', Decimal('3353.54000000000'), -23.0), ('Telephone', '2019', 'JUL', Decimal('200'), 200.0)]>
```

**Incorrect when used with changelist_view queryset:**

```
qs = response.context_data['cl'].queryset
extra_context['summary'] = qs.values_list('category__name', 'year', 'month').annotate(
            Sum('amount'), due=Sum(F('amount') - F('paid_amount'), output_field=models.FloatField()))

print(extra_context['summary'])

<QuerySet [('Telephone', '2019', 'AUG', Decimal('1677'), -23.0), ('Telephone', '2019', 'JUL', Decimal('500'), 500.0), ('Telephone', '2019', 'AUG', Decimal('1676.54000000000'), 0.0), ('Telephone', '2019', 'JUL', Decimal('-300'), -300.0), ('Insurance', '2019', 'FEB', Decimal('35200.2300000000'), 25200.230000000003)]>
```

Above see that AUG 2019 not grouped correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked correctly when used along with `order_by` function on the queryset.